# How to use two physical NIC's inside a Xen guest?

Tags: xen, nic, bridge

I'm trying to make two physical interfaces visible to a Xen machine.

I followed the guide (http://idolinux.blogspot.com/2008/08/xen-add-network-bridge-for-eth1.html), and created two Xen bridges for two physical interfaces / updated the guest config file with the new bridge.

The problem is that my guest machines are still unable to see the eth1.

I'll appreciate anyone who had success with this posting any notes or checklist.

The host (Dom0) is CentOS 5.5 64-bit, guest is CentOS 5.3 64-bit. The used Xen is version 3.0.3.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is the output of brctl show: http://pastie.org/private/km5bixaem3o0yzrv4cqcsa

Comment: Here is the DomU config file: http://pastie.org/private/eeqlanvnez0e4hvobhhdig

Comment: Ifconfig output: http://pastie.org/private/3n6mpfwx4fleowaawjdsiw

Comment: Have you considered using PCI passthrough for the NICS?

Comment: xm create -n shows two NICs? Have you stopped your vm, deleted it from management and recreated it (whith new or create)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has a few links and seemingly a solution: [Xen NICs](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=24513)

Comment: I have the part described there set-up successfully, including normal output from the brctl show command with two bridges:http://pastie.org/private/km5bixaem3o0yzrv4cqcsa

Comment: Please see above the rest of diagnostic output.

Comment: I have to admit I'm stumped. What's `route -n` show ? Maybe someone else can chip in too.